# Binding JSON child object property into Java object field in Jackson

Tags: java, json, data-binding, jackson

I have a JSON object, say:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": 1
  },
  "baz": 2
}
```

and I want to bind it into a Java object, like:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Foo {
  private int bar;
  @JsonProperty("baz")
  private int baz;
}
```

How can I set the value of `foo.bar` from JSON to the `bar` field in the `Foo` Java object?

I've tried annotating the field with `@JsonProperty("foo.bar")`, but it doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This ain't perfect but it's the most elegant way I could figure out.

```
@JsonProperty("foo")
public void setFoo(Map<String, Object> foo) {
  bar = (Integer) foo.get("bar");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no automated functionality for this (as far as I know), but this is a somewhat often requested feature; there is this Jira RFE: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-132 that sounds like what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes that's the same issue, though I'd use it for deserialization. I guess my solution above is the best I can get if I don't want to change the structure of the `Foo` object.

Answer (score -4):

Here a quick example that works:

**JSON:**

```
[{"function":{"name":"Function 1"}},
 {"function":{"name":"Function 2"}}]
```

**Java:**

```
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Function {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("function")
    public void setFunction(Map<String, Object> function) {
      name = (String) function.get("name");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the need to include a bunch of lombok stuff in your answer? It would actually have the same result without those.

Answer (score -18):

That's like binding an apple to an orange! Another 'catchy phrase' would be, "Impedance Mismatch", or in Star Trek 1, "Non Sequetor!" Bind it a MATCHED object, then do new assignment in Java between the different kinds of objects.

Comment: Not really helpful. I wouldn't like to create useless Java classes just because someone couldn't design a decent JSON API.

Comment: Agreed with @hleinone. One is not always in control of the API and having to create nested classes/maps/hacks/voodoo is not the right solution.