# Parse JSON tree to plain class using Jackson or its alternatives

Tags: java, json, jackson

How to parse that JSON:

```
{
    "foo": {
        "bar": {
            "baz": "Hello"
        },
        "qux": "World"
    }
}
```

Into that class using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) or its alternatives:

```
public class Foo {
    private String baz;
    private String qux;

    public String getBaz() {
        return baz;
    }

    public void setBaz(final String baz) {
        this.baz = baz;
    }

    public String getQux() {
        return qux;
    }

    public void setQux(final String qux) {
        this.qux = qux;
    }
}
```

Expecting something like:

```
@JsonProperty("foo.bar.baz")
private String baz;
@JsonProperty("foo.qux")
private String qux;
```

Comment: Similar question [Binding JSON child object property into Java object field in Jackson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199794/binding-json-child-object-property-into-java-object-field-in-jackson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

This use case may not be possible with Jackson, but can be done when MOXy is used as your JSON-binding provider.

**Foo**

You can take advantage of MOXy's path based mapping for this use case.

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

public class Foo {

    private String baz;
    private String qux;

    @XmlPath("foo/bar/baz/text()")
    public String getBaz() {
        return baz;
    }

    public void setBaz(final String baz) {
        this.baz = baz;
    }

    @XmlPath("foo/qux/text()")
    public String getQux() {
        return qux;
    }

    public void setQux(final String qux) {
        this.qux = qux;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

The JAXB runtime APIs are used to read/write the JSON.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Foo.class}, properties);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StreamSource json = new StreamSource("src/forum15659950/input.json");
        Foo foo = unmarshaller.unmarshal(json, Foo.class).getValue();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.json/Output**

```
{
   "foo" : {
      "bar" : {
         "baz" : "Hello"
      },
      "qux" : "World"
   }
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html

Answer (score 3):

I have found, that this feature is not implemented in [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) yet, see [issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/issues/42).

As a workaround, method below can be added into `Foo` class:

```
@JsonProperty("foo")
public void setFoo(JsonNode jsonNode) {
    this.qux = jsonNode.get("qux").getTextValue();
    this.baz = jsonNode.get("bar").get("baz").getTextValue();
}
```