# Using JSON data as a String object in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, string, parsing

I am using HTTP Client to send different kinds of requests (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE) where I am sending the JSON as a data to post with different requests.

I have a JSON data like:

```
{ "createdByID": "100000", "createdByName": "Admin", "modifiedByID": "100000", "modifiedByName": "Admin" }
```

Now, to store this JSON into a string, I have to add double quotes wherever necessary so that this can be stored as

```
String jsonData = "{" + "\"" + "createdByID" + "\"" + ":" + "\"" +  "100000" + "\"" + "," + "\"" + "createdByName" + "\"" + ":" + "\"" + "Admin" + "\"" + "," + "\"" + "modifiedByID" + "\"" + ":" + "\"" +  "100000" + "\"" + "," + "\"" + "modifiedByName" + "\"" + ":" + "\"" + "Admin" + "\"" + "}"
```

Does anyone use any tool/utility to convert the JSON data such that it can be stored in a string object?

Please share if anyone has already done this

Comment: Quite unclear what you're asking. It is a string, it doesn't need any conversions. If you mean to add escapings to quotes, use any text editor's search and replace. And there is no need for all the separate strings and pluses

Comment: If you want to convert JSon object to String then you can use any JSON parsing library.

Comment: I think that he meant that the field is being handled as JSON and he need it as plain String, in this case this answer can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15665014/3211175

Comment: Can you not do `jsonData = jsonObj.toString()` function leveraging the built in `toString()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you store the json as a sting in your code then only you need to add double codes.

> Try to read json from a text file , then you don't need to add double quotes and other stuffs.

More over java does not consider double quotes after compiling your code.